# Continuous decomposition of permutation-invariant set functions

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, symmetric-functions, machine-learning

The seminal machine learning paper [Deep Sets (Zaheer et al., 2017)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.06114) discusses representations of *permutation-invariant* functions on real tuples, or (multi)set functions.

Given a countable set $X$ and a function $f : \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} \binom{X}{k} \to \mathbb R$ operating on *finite sets*, it is [easy to prove](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.06114.pdf#subsection.A.1) $f$ has a decomposition
\begin{align}
  f \left(\{x_1, \ldots, x_k\} \right) = \rho \left( \sum_{i=1}^k \phi(x_k) \right),
\end{align}
for functions $\rho, \phi : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. (Note $k$ is not fixed here.)

This motivates approximating set functions using $\phi$ and $\rho$ from some restricted function class (neural networks). There have been successful applications, most prominently in graph neural networks.

However, I'm strongly doubtful of the applicability of the motivating decomposition.

1. Consider a very simple case: $f : \bigcup_{k} \binom{\mathbb N}{k} \to \mathbb R$ operates on finite sets, and is given by a symmetric polynomial for each $k$, that is,
   \begin{align}
     f \left(\{x_1, \ldots, x_k\} \right) = P_k \left(x_1, \ldots, x_k \right).
   \end{align}
   If we choose $\phi(x) = 2^x$, we may obviously decompose $f(S) = \rho(\sum_{x \in S} 2^x)$ for $\rho$ continuous. 
   Can we take $\rho$ and $\phi$ to be continuous and *bounded by some polynomial*?